# How to use Google charts with data from stored procedure with an input parameter in asp.net webform with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

I want to create a Google chart using a stored procedure with Entity Framework in a Webforms application. I am struggling with the code of Google script which the chart uses.

My stored procedure (I am using Entity Framework) takes one input parameter and accordingly chart should be generated..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[netsales] 
@CompanyCode int

AS
SELECT        PeriodData.Periodendson, IncomeStatement.NetSales,
Company.CompanyCode                                                
FROM            Company INNER JOIN
                     PeriodData ON Company.CompanyCode =   
PeriodData.CompanyCode INNER JOIN
                     IncomeStatement ON PeriodData.Periodid =  
IncomeStatement.Periodid
WHERE        (Company.CompanyCode = @CompanyCode)
```

how to create **google chart** from above **stored procedure** using **entity framework** in asp.net webform? CompanyCode will be provided by user.

Comment: ***SHOW US SOMETHING!*** We cannot possibly help you if you don't provide ***anything at all!***

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[netsales] @CompanyCode int AS SELECT        PeriodData.Periodendson, IncomeStatement.NetSales, Company.CompanyIncomeFROM Company INNER JOIN
 PeriodData ON Company.CompanyCode = PeriodData.CompanyCode INNER JOIN
                         IncomeStatement ON PeriodData.Periodid = IncomeStatement.Periodid
WHERE        (Company.CompanyCode = @CompanyCode)                                I have this stored procedure.CompanyCode is user input . I want to create google chart from this using entity framework.I want a code of javascript(google chart) and code on .aspx.cs page

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for correcting!!Edited my question